# What happens to tty serial port contents after a write operation?

Tags: tty, serial-port

I am using a PC (Windows 10) to communicate with an Jetson Development Kit running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
The PC has a C program that sends data via UART and Ubuntu is supposed to read that data also using a C program.

My question is, what should I expect the contents of my tty file (/dev/ttyTHS2) to be after the PC has written some raw bytes into it? Is the contents cleared after the write operation? Does it just append the file and move a cursor? Is there an upper limit to what the tty file can store at a given moment until it is cleared?

I can't find the answers when I searched online, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I answer in a different order so my answers make more sense.

#### Does [writing to the tty] just append the file and move a cursor?

Not really. A tty is not a block device, but a *character* device. You write a single byte to the device file which ultimately results in the UART becoming active transferring the bits. The process is repeated for multiple bytes.

#### Is there an upper limit to what the tty file can store at a given moment until it is cleared?

Yes, there is an upper limit. Buffers exist in hardware and software. If you write to the tty faster than it can transfer, the buffers fill up and write operation blocks. I do not know the exact sizes. I would expect a buffer size of 1 (can only write one byte at a time).

#### what should I expect the contents of my tty file (/dev/ttyTHS2) to be after the PC has written some raw bytes into it?

As far as I know, ttys do not echo by default. When reading from the tty file, the operation blocks until a byte is *received* from the outside.

A tty does only know bytes. There are no "raw" or "cooked" bytes.

#### Is the contents cleared after the write operation?

You normally do not read from the write buffer, so this does not matter.

All these answers assume a tty which has been configured via IOCTLs.

Comment: That was really helpfull. Thank you! Especially the part about the upper limit of the tty. The reason I asked is because I am using C with termios.h library to receive 20 bytes (on Linux side) at baud rate of 230400. I have a way of detecting errors in the 20 bytes I send, they are coded in some way. So what happens is that a bit or bits change during transmission and I discard the 20 bytes. So I am wondering if my program maybe can't read the data as fast as it is written just like you said "If you write to the tty faster than it can transfer, the buffer fill up and write operation blocks".